# Posição de um cavalo no jogo de xadrez

Tags: c

Estou aprendendo `C`.
Meu professor da faculdade pediu para fazer um programa que leia a posição de um cavalo no jogo de xadrez e imprima TODAS as possibilidades de movimento.

Eu estou quebrando a cabeça pra saber como eu vou saber a letra e o número que o usuário pediu?

Comment: Use um array para mapear o tabuleiro, para a posição que o usuário pediu use uma variável simples já que o intuito é você mapear as possibilidades do movimento de uma peça. Ha e boa sorte na matéria de processamento paralelo se vocês tiverem no curso (;

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/

Answer (score 1):

```
// criar o tabuleiro
char tabuleiro[8][8];

// Pede ao usuário informar a posição da peça que deseja mover
printf("Digite a linha onde esta sua peca: ");
scanf("%d", &linAtual);
printf("Digite a coluna onde esta sua peca: ");
scanf("%d", &colAtual);

// Pede ao usuário informar para onde deseja que a peça vá
printf("Digite a linha desejada: ");
scanf("%d", &linDes);
printf("Digite a colun desejada: ");
scanf("%d", &colDes);

// Você pode usar essas informações do usuário pra localizar e mover a peça
char peca = tabuleiro [colAtual][linAtual];
tabuleiro [colAtual][linAtual] = " ";
tabuleiro [colDes][linDes]= peca;
```

Então cara vc vai ter que pensar em como diferenciar as peças(dá pra ter uma ideia pelo código acima) e também vai ter que definir as regras de movimentação (muito if e  else) boa sorte.

Answer (score -4):

Eu fiz um algorítmo relacionado à torre do xadrez. A saída mostra o mapa de movimentos que ela pode realizar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int linha = 0, coluna = 0;
    int i, j;

    printf("Movimentos de uma Torre no xadrez!\n");

    printf("Digite a linha em que a Torre se encontra: ");
    scanf("%d", &linha);

    printf("Digite a coluna em que a Torre se encontra: ");
    scanf("%d", &coluna);

    printf("    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8\n   -----------------");

    for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++){


        if (i != linha){

            if (coluna == 1){

                printf("\n%d | x - - - - - - -", i);
            }

            if (coluna == 2){

                printf("\n%d | - x - - - - - -", i);
            }
            if (coluna == 3){

                printf("\n%d | - - x - - - - -", i);
            }

            if (coluna == 4){

                printf("\n%d | - - - x - - - -", i);
            }

            if (coluna == 5){

                printf("\n%d | - - - - x - - -", i);
            }

            if (coluna == 6){

                printf("\n%d | - - - - - x - -", i);
            }
            if (coluna == 7){

                printf("\n%d | - - - - - - x -", i);
            }

            if (coluna == 8){

                printf("\n%d | - - - - - - - x", i);
            }


        }

        else if (i == linha){

        printf("\n%d | x x x x x x x x", i);

        }

    }




    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Se o autor da pergunta quisesse saber quais todas as posições da torre ele teria escrito *Gostaria de saber como obter todas as possibilidade de movimento de uma torre partir de dada posição* mas ele pediu a posição do cavalo então entregue a ele ao autor da pergunta o que ele pediu ou não entregue nada, mas atenha ao que foi perguntado.